# Incorrect "Users" Aggregation in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio, calculation

I'm having trouble figuring out why "Users" are being calculated incorrectly in Google Data Studio (GDS). Based on the attached image, clearly the number of "Users" do not add up to 6,434:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Henry, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 0):

The summary line, indicating the grand total, has no direct connection with the value present in each of the lines. The grand total will be the result of the operation defined for your column applied to all rows in your database.

Without knowing which metric you are using to generate the number of users, it is not possible to objectively define the problem. I suggest you check which aggregation is used in the "user" column and check if applying this aggregation to the database as a whole can generate the displayed value in the grand total.